# How can I create a border around an input button?

Tags: css

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWaXf/)

I have this code where I tried to make a button have a blue line around it. But when I ran the code I just get a blue line at the top of the button. I added `disply: inline-block` but that doesn't seem to work. Is there some way I can make the `div`'s border surround the input button?

```
<div id="A">
   <div style="border: 1px solid Blue">
      <input style="float: left; display: block" type="button" onclick="doTest('total'); return false;" />
   </div>
   <div id="B" style="display: block; float: left;">ABC</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why all those divs?

See [demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/yHvmG/1/).

HTML:

```
<form id="A" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <span><input id="button1" type="button" value="Caption" onclick="" /></span>
        <label id="B" for="button1">ABC</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#A span {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove "float: left" from your input and add it to the surrounding div.

Comment: Beat me to it by a couple of seconds!

Comment: But then the text goes below the button which is not what I wanted :-(

Comment: Try SPAN instead of DIV  or "display: inline". That would arrange your elements in a row.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="A">
   <div style="border: 1px solid Blue;float:left">
      <input style="display: block" type="button" onclick="doTest('total'); return false;" />
   </div>
   <div id="B" style="display: block; float: left; margin-left:100px;">ABC</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting height on a DIV that wraps INPUT can help:

```
<div id="A">
   <div style="border: 1px solid Blue; height: 20px;">
      <input style="float: left; display: block" type="button" onclick="doTest('total'); return false;" />
   </div>
   <div id="B" style="display: block; float: left;">ABC</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text ABC inside the blue border you have to move it inside the div with the border, combined with the height "trick" as suggested by [spektom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316315/how-can-i-create-a-border-around-an-input-button/6316338#6316338).

```
<div id="A">
   <div style="border: 1px solid Blue; min-height:20px">
      <input style="float: left; display: block"
             type="button"
             onclick="doTest('total'); return false;" />
      <div id="B" style="display: block; float: left;">ABC</div>
  </div>
</div>
```